# Maximum update Depth Exceeded - wrapping animated component in a modal?

Tags: react-native

Having a problem here. Essentially trying to create an animation for a modal pop up when a button is tapped.

Because I have a tab bar in the application, To let the modal pop up over the tab bar, I need to wrap the Animated Component in a Modal (or maybe I don't? Would be good to know other solutions). This means that when I toggle the animation, I also want to toggle local state for the modal's visibility.

However, when I hit the button, the component updates through redux and calls the toggleModal function - the inclusion of `this.setState(prevState => ({ modalVisible: !prevState.modalVisible }))` is somehow causing a repetitive call of `setState`.

I have the animation working in a throwaway expo app without `useNativeDriver` and without a tab bar (thus not needing a modal component to wrap the animation).

How can I begin to fix this?

**AddCircleModal:**

```
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height

class AddCircleModal extends React.Component {
    state = {
        top: new Animated.Value(screenHeight),
        modalVisible: false
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        ('modalDidUpdate')
        this.toggleModal()
    }

    toggleModal = () => {
    console.log('toggled')
    this.setState(prevState => ({ modalVisible: !prevState.modalVisible })) //if I have this line I'm getting 'maximum update depth exceeded' error
        if (this.props.action === 'openModal') {
            Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
                toValue: 174,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }).start()
        }
        if (this.props.action === 'closeModal') {
            Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
                toValue: screenHeight,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }).start()
    }
}


    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
             transparent={true}
             visible={this.state.modalVisible}
             >
                 <AnimatedContainer style={{scaleY: this.state.top}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={this.props.closeModal}
                            style={{ position: "absolute", top: 120, left: "50%", marginLeft: -22, zIndex: 1 }}
                     >
                        <Text>GO</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                 </AnimatedContainer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

const Container = styled.View`
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 22px;
`

const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Container)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { action: state.action }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        closeModal: () =>
            dispatch({
                type: "CLOSE_MODAL"
            })
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddCircleModal)
```

Comment: can you add expo snack?

Comment: Sure, https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/jamiestirrat/rn-animations. Although this is a throwaway app to test the animation - the app in the question is built on vanilla react native

Comment: Ahh just realised the snack won't work as it needs react-redux